# How to emit custom event in ReteJs?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I need to emit custom events in ReteJS, how can I do it?

I have googled quite a bit before finding the way out of this. If you want to listen/trigger custom event you need to first register it to the editor with "bind" command, then you can listen for it or trigger it with some payload.

Related documentation link (unfortunately at least now, it says nothing about custom events binding or triggering the events) https://rete.js.org/#/docs/events

Answer (score 0):

That's how:

```js
  // bind - enable new event type be be triggered/listened
  editor.bind('nodeupdated');

  // start listen for event, you may pass in several events separate with space: "event1 event2 event3"
  editor.on('nodeupdated', (data) => {
    console.log(`#202114585959280 nodeupdated:: `, data);
  });

  // trigger event with some payload
  editor.trigger('nodeupdated', {foo: 'bar'});
```